# How to create PDF with table of contents or links to sections inside the header with pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I would like to create a PDF document from an markdown file, and I need it to have the Table of Contents in every page, could be in header, footer or anywhere.

To be more specific: I'm generating pdfs from every chapter of the bible that I have in markdown, but is necessary to have an easy way to navigate. Then I'm going to put links in header to the other books and chapters and the table of contents would profide links for the verses inside the current chapter.

[image: Genesis Chapter 1 example]

This is an example of Genesis Chapter 01. In header should be the links to another books, chapters and verses.

I'm using this command to generate my pdf. If i use the `--toc` option it generates the TOC but I just want the TOC as links in the header, not the table itself in the beggining.

`pandoc -H some_file --latex-engine=xelatex -V urlcolor=cyan test.md -o 01.pdf`

Can I put something in `-H some_file` to create that links (maybe would be easier than generate the toc in the header) or use the toc?

I tried to use the following header template:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\href{teste.pdf}{secao}}
\lhead{\ref{01.md}{refsimples}}
\cfoot{Fancy in the footer}
```

I'm able to create links to outside docs, but not links to sections in the document.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at the `etoc` package. It allows to insert local toc into arbitrary places and provides a powerful interface to customise the appearance to whatever you want.

Comment: Not relevant to this question, but I note that you use `--latex-engine`, which means that you still use pandoc 1.x. Pandoc 2 contains many improvements, you may want to give it a try. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases

Comment: Thank you for the tips, will try pandoc2 and etoc package!